# Find missing numbers given the sum

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Sam was given a task to add up numbers 1 + 2 + 3... up to ten. As he stopped, gave a sum of 37. It was declared that his results are wrong. Later he discovered that he had missed some numbers in the sequence during addition. What are they?

This is a problem of triangular numbers and partitions.

$$1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

So far I've come up with substracting the partial divergent S = 10! with the sum of $37$.

$$\frac{10(10+1)}{2} - 37 = 18.$$

This gives us the sum of all missing numbers. If $18$ was the only missing number then it would be known by now. Because the total count of missing values is arbitrary, it is impossible to solve. **Let's allow that there are three missing numbers**, this gives us some partitions to work with:

- [5, 6, 7]
- [1, 8, 9]
- [3, 5, 10]
- [3, 6, 9]
- [3, 7, 8]
- ...
- [4, 5, 9]

Which is far too many. There should be only one match. This is a real head-scratcher.

1. How to find all the missing numbers in a sequence?
2. How to find which partition matches the missing sequence?
3. if all else fails, how to find only the lowest and highest missing values?
4. All values are positive integers and unique.

Comment: probably he missed CONSECUTIVE numbers, so I would favour the solution that Sam missed $5,6,7$

Comment: @Peter: Unfortunately that suggestion still doesn't make the solution unique, because 18=3+4+5+6 too.

Comment: If Sam missed exactly two numbers, the only soltuion would be that he missed $8$ and $10$.

Comment: @Peter, the solution to two numbers is 

$$ y_1^2 + y_2^2 = (\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}) $$

$$  A = y_1 + y_2, B =  y_1y_2   $$

form polynomial,

$$ x^2 - Ax + B $$ then find their roots. roots will be 8 and 10